# Trying to float inputs and spans inline

Tags: css

I'm trying to float a few inputs next to each other with dots between them to simulate an IPv4 address; however, the span is floating in the middle. How can I fix this? All of the elements in this picture have float:left applied.

http://tinypic.com/r/33magcz/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs and spans are inline elements, you don't need to float them at all.

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="ip0" class"ipAddress">
<span class"ipAddress">.</span>
<input type="text" size="3" name="ip1" class"ipAddress">
<span class"ipAddress">.</span>
<input type="text" size="3" name="ip2" class"ipAddress">
<span class"ipAddress">.</span>
<input type="text" size="3" name="ip3" class"ipAddress">
<span class"ipAddress">.</span>
```

Use CSS `position: relative;` and `top:` to align elements vertically.

---

From a user's perspective I find four separate input boxes for an IP-address rather unfriendly. It's harder to type and copy/paste does not work, which is a big drawback.

From the application's perspective there is not much to gain from separate input boxes.

I'd say, dump the idea and provide a single input field.

Comment: That may be true, but it's also harder to mess up. These aren't technical users and the visual indication should help them. I can parse it out into a machine-readable IP address myself. Are you sure it isn't possible to copy/paste into the first box and have it flow over into the rest?

Comment: @sean Yes, you can add JavaScript that handles the paste event and acts accordingly. But copying will be impossible. OTOH, you can also add a JavaScript that only accepts things that match an IP address and make a single input work.